# How to find common elements in several List(of)?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, list

I have three lists as follow

```
Dim foodList1 As New List(Of Food)
Dim foodList2 As New List(Of Food)
Dim foodList3 As New List(Of Food)

Dim resualt = From c In db.Food
              Where c.Code = X
              Select c

m_FoodList1 = resualt.ToList
```

I need to create a new list containing the foods that these three lists have in common.
Is there any method that I can use instead of going through lists and comparing them ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is a food guaranteed to be unique within a list ?

Comment: Check the [Intersect() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for this purpose. This works on a HashSet internally so its performance is very good:

```
Dim result = foodList1.Intersect(foodList2).Intersect(foodList3)
```

If the Food class does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` yet, you can create a special [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and supply it as a parameter to [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Class FoodEqualityComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Food)

    Public Function Equals(x As Food, y As Food) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Food).Equals
        Return x.Code = y.Code
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode(x As Food) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Food).GetHashCode
        Return x.Code.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class

' ...

Dim eqComp As New FoodEqualityComparer()
Dim result = foodList1.Intersect(foodList2, eqComp).Intersect(foodList3, eqComp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Dim resualt = From fl1 In foodList1
              Join fl2 In fooldList2
              On fl1.Code Equals fl2.Code
              Join fl3 In foodList3
              On fl1.Code Equals fl3.Code
              Select fl1

m_FoodList1 = resualt.ToList
```

Using the above way, you make a join between the three lists. Hence you get their common foods.

For documentation of joins in linq please take a look here [How to: Combine Data with LINQ by using Joins (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx).